# port number for the virtual directory in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

Is there any way to mention the port number for the virtual directory in IIS. Mt IIs version is 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to IIS Manager.
- Open the properties windows of Default Web Site.
- Select the Web Site Tab.
- Under web site identification, you can change the default 80 port or you can click on Advanced tab and then can change the default 80 port.

Comment: Question was about virtual directory not about web site.